# Can I upgrade an program via group policy if it was initially installed manualy?

Tags: group-policy, deployment, update

We have a program which was installed manually on workstations when they were initially setup. We now need to upgrade this software and I wish to do it via group policy.

I have created an MST using Orca. It appears to work using `msiexec /i application.msi /q TRANSFORMS=my_mst.mst`. However when we add the package and MST to deploy via Group Policy, the application does not update. It is applied as a computer configuration to avoid any issues with users admin rights.

From my understanding the behavior of group policy software deployment should match that of `msiexec /i application.msi /q TRANSFORMS=my_mst.mst`. Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: It SHOULD work exactly as you have described: the same as the results of running the command locally. We all know how that works, however. You need to pull up Event Viewer and see what's being logged. That will give you whatever return value the installation produces, allowing you to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the question. You specify an mst file after the /i switch? I thought that must be an msi. And you update using an mst? I though that was done with an msp. msp files cannot be deployed with GPO.

Comment: This is an old thread, which my question was answered however than you for pointing out error. I have updated so it references '.msi' after /i switch. you do not necessarily need to use .mst file to update msi. Using .mst (or custom scripts within an msi) you can change properties of the MSI to allow an upgrade of an application installed by MSI

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying this as a Computer Policy, you need to make sure that "Domain Computers" has access to the share that these files are on.

You can test this by running `psexec -s -I cmd.exe` and running your command again. This will give you an interactive command prompt as the system user, which is the same context that the computer GPO would process with.